# Brake lights, but no tail lights

Tags: jeep, tail-lights, fuse

I've got a 2001 WJ 4.0, The right brake light wasn't working, so I installed a new bulb, but I must have done something in the process because now all my brake lights work but I have no running lights. My dash lights all work, and I can't find any blown fuses.

Edit:Brake lights, turn signals, and reverse lights all work, but no running lights which are the same bulb as the brake lights. Does anyone know which fuse(s) I should inspect specifically? The fuse chart is cryptic at best, this weekend I may eventually resort to scrutinizing every fuse in the jeep.

Comment: Check the wiring you may have moved during replacement, maybe there's bad contact or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its fairly common for these to burn out sockets for the bulbs, and even often on both sides at the same time. The socket can be removed asa separate piece, and it is fairly likely melted and/or burned

Comment: Do you think I should try getting two of these? http://www.amazon.com/Dorman-923-034-Tail-Lamp-Socket/dp/B000TYSBYY/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1356035494&sr=8-1&keywords=2001+jeep+wj+brake+light+socket

Comment: I would check it first. If they are burned out, check for voltage where they are installed as in rarer cases a whole lens is needed

Comment: I think you're really on to something here. I was able to get the right brake light and tail light to work completely by forcefully reinserting the socket several times, leading me to believe that the socket contacts are burnt or old.

Comment: Like I said, I've seen it a lot

Answer (score 4):

If the tail lights were hot during the swap you may have broken the filiments. Bumping a bulb that is on or been on recently can cause the filiments to fail. Remove the bulbs hold them up to a light and see if the filimant is intact.

Comment: Sorry mate, it's not the filaments. These are new bulbs, remember? It's possible the bulbs are somehow otherwise faulty, but a simply broken filament isn't what's giving me grief.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the relay under the dash for the parking/running lights, I just fixed one in my shop 10 mins ago that needed the relay and new bulbs (bad bulb on one side caused all brake/run lights to go out if the running lights were on when applying the brakes) also check the sockets and contacts as well

Answer (score 1):

So I was having the same exact problem on my 99 WJ Laredo. I looked for everything I could all damn day. I finally got to my last resort and just started pulling and checking fuses. Sure enough, the F23 Brake switch fuse was blown. I replaced it, and everything works like a charm now.

Another symptom of my issue was that one brake light was dimmer than the other, so check for that as well to double assure your situation. It's also important to remember that your sockets and bulbs must be in good shape. I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.  I couldn't figure out why I was having the same problem on my trailer rear lights so I knew the problem wasn't solely with the wiring at my rear tail lights.  Check the 15 amp fuse for Park #6 fuse.  I looked at the fuse in place at least 5 times and it didn't seem blown until I removed it and it was blown.  Replaced and night time running lights came on.

Also, you will need to check the contact points on the top bulb, well all three but in this instance the top bulb.  The metal contacts burn hot and oxidizes causing you to lose connection.  I have in the past added a strip of aluminum foil to fix.  Also I used electric grease to make contact.  One other thing you can do is to replace the rear assembly for $50 per assembly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Its on the driver side fuse box( which is actually called pasanger fuse box)! Its number 6 a 15 amp fuse its labeled as park lights!