# Tail light is intermittently out on Dodge Caravan

Tags: electrical, dodge, tail-lights

I have a 2004 Dodge Grand Caravan. A couple of days ago, the right turn signal started flashing rapidly when turned on to indicate a burned out bulb. I checked and found the right tail light was completely out.

However, before I could get a replacement bulb, the turn signal returned to normal operation, and I found that the light was coming on again. Now it's out again. I replaced the bulb, which didn't fix the problem (and the filament in the old bulb looks perfectly good as well.

I suspect this is likely being caused by a loose/frayed wire somewhere (I also had a previous problem with the power sliding doors tracked down to a wire that apparently frequently gets damaged in normal operation on Caravans). Any suggestions where I should start looking?

Comment: I had the same problem with my chrysler: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/4978/brake-lights-but-no-tail-lights

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a similar problem before and it turned out to be the socket for the bulb was bad.  I'd start with inspecting wiring that you can see, but proving wiring "good" is pretty much impossible (and replacing it is likely to be a major chore).  It might just be cheaper/easier to try and replace the socket first and see what happens.  Sorry I can't be more detailed, but I'm unfamiliar with details of Caravan wiring.

Comment: I agree, it'll be a poor connection somewhere, and the socket itself is the usual suspect. If you can get to it, try taking the bulb out and cleaning the contacts inside the socket with fine emery paper.